# grails controller - POST json request

Tags: json, grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have very simple controller with the following method:

```
def createNewWidgetVersion() {
        println request.JSON
        render status: OK
}
```

I'm sending the following request:

> POST /CMSAdmin/widgetVersion/createNewWidgetVersion HTTP/1.1 Host:
>   localhost:8080
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> { "htmlText":"33", "javaScript":
>   "document.getElementById('ffsdfdsfsfsfsd')", "comments":"SUCCESS",
>   "widgetId": "1", "type": "LIVE" }

and when debugging, IDE shows that `request.JSON` is empty. Controller doesn't extend RestfullController but I think it doesn't have to in this particular siutation. Could you please give a hint what I'm doing wrong? Spent few hours dealing with this. Thanks!

```
UPD1
```

I added the following to UrlMappings.groovy:

```
"/widgetVersion/"(controller: "widgetVersion", parseRequest:true){
    action = [POST:'createNewWidgetVersion']
}
```

is there any way to avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: try changing type to `text/json`

Comment: @injecteer doesn't help :-(

Comment: Do you use any filter and read the JSON payload from request in it or anywhere before accessing the payload in the action method?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: Does the request body show any data via `request.reader.text`?